# Selecting a row in DataGrid by clicking Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that i am trying to change the selected item by selecting the row and not the cell. As you can see from the image below when i click outside the cell the item doesn't update.

[image: GIF of user trying to select row on blank cell]

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customerListBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"  Margin="10,57,10,10"  AlternationCount="2"  BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"  Header="Name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Phone}"  Header="Phone"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What i can do to get it working is setting the last column width to `*` However this makes the header central and looks messy when displayed on a wide screen monitor.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Email}" Width="*" Header="Email"/>
```

[image: Column when set to *]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have workaround to fix this issue, just add dummy empty column after the last column with **Width="*"**

Comment: Yes that worked and using @danieleSartori `SelectionUnit`made it look tidier. just feels a bit hacky lol

Comment: @Bish25 - the selection with FullRow look for select all row, if you satisfied how its look then his solution is better

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
customerListBox.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
```

You can also use

```
customerListBox.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
```

To allow multiple selection if you need

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried that but had no effect as i believe its because its not got a column assigned. Just wondering if there was a solution instead customising the header.

Comment: Why? they are default values.